# Onclick event of a certain page, perform POST action of other page

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, model-view-controller, jsp

Let me explain my problem with a scenario:
I have webpages "A.jsp" and "B.jsp".
"B.jsp" is a page with a form that requires input field, 'username' and on submission displays a certain page "C.jsp" with user-specific information. "A.jsp" has table with an element that would correspond to 'username' on "B.jsp". Onclick  of a certain 'username' on "A.jsp", I want to be redirected to "C.jsp" with clicked username specific information.

How do I get it done?

I am using MVC framework. Only A.jsp and B.jsp are tied to controller, C.jsp is only a View. But, I believe that is less of an issue, since this seem to be more of a javascript question.

Using prototype javascript framework, I have tried the following:
   redirectToC=function(pageurl){
            var username=document.getElementById("user1").value;
            url=pageurl;   //I am using B.jsp as Pageurl
            $j.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: "username="+username,
                success: function(request){
                    window.location=request;
                }
            });
    }

Comment: @Adeel, Edited the language of the question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Does C.jsp support only POST - or does it support GET requests as well?

1. If it does, in the `onClick` of the 'username' link, set the location of the browser (i think `document.location`) to the URL of C.jsp with the username as a GET parameter. Since you are generating the A.jsp page dynamically, this URL can be embedded into the page at generation time
2. If it does not, a bad hack i can think of is to implement the the table element with the username, as a hidden form element which is submitted via javascript when clicked - `'form'.submit()`

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="showUserForm" action="/controller/showUser" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="username" name="username">
</form>
```

..........

```
<a onclick="showUser('${users.userName}')" href="#"></a>
```

..........

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showUser(userName){
        document.getElementById("username").value = userName;
        document.getElementById("showUserForm").submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: As I said, it is a POST request, not a GET request. And, secondly, I do understand the flow of the sequence in MVC but I am not able to figure out the way to make it work with the code.

Comment: @Curious: Ah fair enough. Updated my answer. Hope this would help now.